# Highlight phtml file in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, phalcon, php

The problem is that PhpStorm doesnt recognize/highlight index.phtml.
When the name is not index, for example somethink like blabla.phtml PhpStorm works fine and I get highlight.

Comment: Please provide an screenshot of whole editor window, including editor tab.

Comment: please check if 'index.phtml' is added to text file patterns in Settings | Editor | File types -> 'Text files' file type. If it is, removing this pattern should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem :)